# How can i write a shell script to display the below output?

Tags: shell

newtext.csv looks like below :

```
Record 1
---------
line 1 line 2 Sample Number: 123456789 (line no. 3) | | | | | Time In: 2012-05-29T10:21:06Z (line no. 21) | | | Time Out: 2012-05-29T13:07:46Z (line no. 30) 

Record 2
----------
line 1 line 2 Sample Number: 363214563 (line no. 3) | | | | | Time In: 2012-05-29T10:21:06Z (line no. 21) | | | Time Out: 2012-05-29T13:07:46Z (line no. 30) 

Record 3
---------
line 1 line 2 Sample Number: 987654321 (line no. 3) | | | | | Time In: 2012-05-29T10:21:06Z (line no. 21) | | | Time Out: 2012-05-29T13:07:46Z (line no. 30)
```

Assume there are such 100 records in a newtext.csv So, now i need the parameters of the entered i/p string, which is something below

```
Input
Enter the search String :
123456789

Output

Sample Number is, Sample Number: 123456789 
Connected Time is,Time In: 2012-05-29T10:21:06Z 
Disconnected Time is, Time Out: 2012-05-29T13:07:46Z
```

This is what exactly i need. Can you please help me with shell scripting for the above mentioned format ?

Comment: `echo "123456789" | xargs -I {} grep "Sample Number: "{} newtext.csv`. So I think a simple grep will be enough. something like `grep "Sample Number: xxxxxxx"  newtext.csv`

Comment: @Neevek ...well, awk makes more sense if one wants to give the _exact_ output given from a single stage; grep still leaves more work to do.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, I offered my first solution before the OP edited his question, it might be the OP didn't describe his question correctly or I didn't get it right~

Answer (score 1):

OK, the input and the desired output are kinda weird, but it's still not difficult to get what you want, try the following:

```
var=123456789
awk -v "var=$var" --exec /dev/stdin newtext.csv <<'EOF'
  ($7 == var) {
    printf("Sample Number is, Sample Number: %s\n", $7);
    printf("Connected Time is, Time In: %s\n", $18);
    printf("Disconnected Time is, Time Out: %s\n", $27);
  }
EOF
```

Comment: I'd consider using a mechanism other than string substitution to get the variable into awk (either exporting through the environment and accessing as ENVIRON["var"], or using awk -v var=value), and splitting it over multiple lines for readability (perhaps even into a script with an awk shebang). Otherwise, looks good.

Comment: I am not sure how the OP will use this line of code, so I assume he will embed this line in his own shell script and he will modify the code a little bit to fit his need, and I think declaring the search string as a variable would be more straightforward. As for readability, I must say you are right.

Comment: I'm not suggesting that the search string not be declared as a variable -- I'm suggesting that that variable be passed in to awk in a way that prevents it from being parsed as part of the script. Think about if the variable contains quotation marks, for instance -- it wouldn't in this specific case, but it's a bad habit to write scripts so that they break in unknown ways on certain inputs.